# Publish Devexpress dll

Tags: asp.net, webforms, devexpress, visual-studio-2019

error 
"Could not load file or assembly 'DevExpress.Data.v19.1' or one of its dependencies. Strong name signature could not be verified.  The assembly may have been tampered with, or it was delay signed but not fully signed with the correct private key. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131045)"
when publish my project on ftp server in vs2019

Answer (score 1):

Good ol' DX-dependency hell... Key-takeaway from your error-message is "*...OR one of its dependencies*". Somehow certain DX-assemblies have implict references to other DX-assemblies. Result is the exact situation you encounter: in your dev-environment everything runs fine until you deploy your app to a machine where DevExpress is NOT installed and sh** hits the fan. Check out the ***Devexpress Assembly Deployment Tool*** that comes with the Installer - it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure, you also published the DevExpress dlls to the ftp server and no file is missing.

Comment: yes. I published the DevExpress dlls to the ftp server and no file is missing